# Justified text alignment with second line indented

Tags: formatting, tex-core

I am pretty new to Tex.

I want to specify bibliography items so that the text allignment is justified throughout the page, but with the second and third lines indented, like so:

[image]

I the above example, I did the indentation manually with \hspace*{5mm}, but as you can see in the first item, it doesn't work well for justified allignment. Is there a way that I could keep the justified allignment of each line, but with the indentation of all but the first line?

I have also not found a bibtex style that would match this requirement. Thank you for your help.

**Updated question**

Here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{SOURCES}

Barbero G., Evangelista L. R., Olivero D. 2000. Asymmetric ionic adsorp-
\hspace*{5mm}tion and cell polarization in liquid crystals. Journal of 
Applied Physics, 87, \hspace*{5mm}5: 2646–2648
\\
\\
Bazant M., Kilic M., Storey B., Ajdari A. 2009. Towards an understanding 
\hspace*{5mm}of induced-charge electrokinetics at large applied voltages in 
concentrated \hspace*{5mm}solutions. Advances in Colloid and Interface 
Science, 152, 2: 48–88
\\
\\
Bhuiyan L. B., Outhwaite C. W., Bratko D. 1992. Structure and thermodynami-
\hspace*{5mm}cs of micellar solutions in the modified Poisson-Boltzmann 
theory. Chemical \hspace*{5mm}Physics Letters, 193: 203–210

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `biblatex` , this is the `authoryear` style (with some differences, such as parentheses around the year).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your help. However, my experience with editing biblatex styles is none.

Comment: Well, post a minimal compilable example that we can play with, and explain what you'd like to change.

Comment: @Bernard see my updated question. The way this code looks now does result is a seemingly justified allignment, but I wonder if there's a way of formatting where the \hspace*{5mm} could be left out.

Comment: You could use the `hanging` package to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is possibly the easiest method.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{sources}
 {\section*{SOURCES}
  \begin{itemize}[
    label={},
    leftmargin=5mm,
    itemindent=-5mm,
    labelwidth=0pt,
    labelsep=0pt,
    itemsep=\bigskipamount,
  ]}
 {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sources}
\item Barbero G., Evangelista L. R., Olivero D. 2000. Asymmetric ionic 
adsorption and cell polarization in liquid crystals. Journal of 
Applied Physics, 87, 5:~2646–2648

\item Bazant M., Kilic M., Storey B., Ajdari A. 2009. Towards an understanding 
of induced-charge electrokinetics at large applied voltages in 
concentrated solutions. Advances in Colloid and Interface 
Science, 152, 2:~48–88

\item Bhuiyan L. B., Outhwaite C. W., Bratko D. 1992. Structure and thermodynamics
of micellar solutions in the modified Poisson-Boltzmann 
theory. Chemical Physics Letters, 193:~203–210
\end{sources}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the `hanging` package, and another with `biblatex-apa` and some patches, which allows citations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[style = apa, backend = biber, maxnames = 6]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch} 

\xpatchbibmacro{name:apa:family-given}{%
\addcomma}{%
}{}{}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\finalandcomma\space}}

   \renewbibmacro*{labelyear+extradate}{%
 \iffieldundef{labelyear}
 {\iffieldundef{origyear}
 {}
 {\printtext{\printorigdate}}}%
 {\printtext{\printlabeldateextra}}}


\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand{\bibhang}{5mm}

\defbibheading{sources}{\section*{SOURCES}}
%
\begin{document}

\section*{SOURCES}

\begin{hangparas}{5mm}{1}
Barbero G., Evangelista L. R., Olivero D. 2000. Asymmetric ionic adsorption and cell polarization in liquid crystals. Journal of Applied Physics, 87, 5: 2646–2648

Bazant M., Kilic M., Storey B., Ajdari A. 2009. Towards an understanding of induced-charge electrokinetics at large applied voltages in concentrated solutions. Advances in Colloid and Interface Science, 152, 2: 48–88

Bhuiyan L. B., Outhwaite C. W., Bratko D. 1992. Structure and thermodynamics of micellar solutions in the modified Poisson-Boltzmann theory. Chemical Physics Letters, 193: 203–210
\end{hangparas}
\bigskip

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading = sources]

\end{document}
```

The `sources.bib` file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{BEO,
  author    = {Barbero, G. and Evangelista, L. R. and Olivero, D.},
  title     = {Asymmetric ionic adsorption and cell polarization in liquid crystals},
  journal   = {Journal of Applied Physics},
  year      = {2000},
  volume    = {87},
  number    = {5},
  pages     = {2646–2648},
  owner     = {Bernard},
  timestamp = {26.2018.01},
}

@Article{BKSA,
  author    = {Bazant, M. and Kilic, M. and Storey, B. and Ajdari, A.},
  title     = {Towards an understanding of induced-charge electrokinetics at large applied voltages in concentrated solutions},
  journal   = {Advances in Colloid and Interface Science},
  year      = {2009},
  volume    = {152},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {48–88},
  owner     = {Bernard},
  timestamp = {26.2018.01},
}

@Article{BOB,
  author    = {Bhuiyan, L. B. and Outhwaite, C. W. and Bratko, D.},
  title     = {Structure and thermodynamics of micellar solutions in the modified Poisson-Boltzmann theory},
  journal   = {Chemical Physics Letters},
  year      = {1992},
  volume    = {193},
  pages     = {203–210},
  owner     = {Bernard},
  timestamp = {26.2018.01},
}
```

[image]